# How did the term "caret" for text insertion evolve?

Tags: editor, history, caret

Where did the term "caret" originate for a text insertion point?  I've tried to google for it, but this is something difficult to locate (even my historic computer reference books don't seem to help here).

I'm reasonably sure I remember some archaic Wang/mainframe apps that used a literal caret (ie: ^) as a text insertion mark, but I couldn't remember one for the life of me.

```
This is an example using the caret as an insertion point^
```

Yeah, I know that I can find the meaning of caret by googling it directly, but I'm looking for for a real etymology here - ie: someone who has used a text editor system with a real, live caret symbol as a text insertion point.  This sort of stuff is interesting to me - like the origin of the use of the term "bug" for a mouse pointer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101548/why-is-the-called-a-caret-closed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes from pen-and-paper text editing, where a ^ mark is used to indicate inserted text.  The mark is named for its purpose according to the Latin derivation noted by others.

Answer (score 4):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) "The term comes from the Latin caret, "it lacks", from 'carēre', to lack;" you use it in marking typos to show where to insert a correction

Answer (score 2):

> This term came about from older unix
>   systems that used the caret symbol as
>   a text insertion indicator

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(computers)

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) says:

> ...comes from the Latin caret, "it lacks", from 'carēre', to lack; to be separated from; to be free from...

Comment: Odd, the more interesting quote is "The caret was originally used, and continues to be, in handwritten form as a proofreading mark to indicate where a punctuation mark, word, or phrase should be inserted in a document. "